# Find duplicates on multiple columns in a SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, asp-classic

I want to find the batchID who are having subjectID(0,1,2) only, pls help me, thanks in advance

I need answer BatchID=12 and BatchID=51, what can I do in sql

MyTable

```
uid BatchID SubjectID
6   2   0
7   2   1
8   2   2
9   2   4
10  3   0
11  3   1
12  4   5
13  4   0
14  5   5
15  6   5
17  7   0
18  7   1
19  7   2
26  12  0
27  12  1
28  12  2
29  1   0
30  1   1
31  1   4
62  45  5
63  46  0
64  46  1
65  46  4
107 49  6
108 49  2
109 49  4
110 50  1
111 50  3
116 0   1
117 0   4
118 51  0
119 51  1
120 51  2
```

Comment: please show your expected output,also include table creation statements to make it easy for others

Comment: why not batchid 46?

Comment: Why is `BatchId 7` not included?

Comment: why is BatchId 2 not included ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select batchId
from your_table
group by batchId
having count(distinct case when subjectID in (0,1,2) then subjectID end) = 3
and count(case when subjectID not in (0,1,2) then 1 end) = 0
```

Explanation:

- `Group by batchId` - Aggregate on batchId
- `count(distinct case when subjectID in (0,1,2) then subjectID end)` - Produces 3 only if all three of them are present for this batchId
- `count(case when subjectID not in (0,1,2) then 1 end)` - Produces 0 if there is no other subjectID except 0,1,2 assuming nulls are not allowed in the subjectId column.

Comment: pls help me on these question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368121/catch-multiple-type-of-data-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row_Number()

```
;with cte as (
    select *, RowN = row_number() over (partition by batchid order by uid) from #yourbatch where subjectid in (0,1,2)
) select distinct BatchId from cte where RowN > 1
```